# D3 Projection_Transform attr

Tags: svg, d3.js, transform, projection, translate

I've got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null` in the line `translate(${projection([longitude, latitude]).join(",")})`. I've already checked that my var `locations` has data in it:

[image]

So, can't understand where is the problem?

Full js-code:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as topojson from "topojson-client";
import us from "./us.json";
import data from "./wm.json"; 

const width = 975;
const height = 610;

const projection = d3
  .geoAlbersUsa()
  .scale(1300)
  .translate(width / 2, height / 2);

const path = d3.geoPath();
const svg = d3.create("svg").attr("height", height).attr("width", width);

const worldMap = svg
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", "#ddd")
  .attr("d", path(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.nation)));

const worldBorders = svg
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("d", path(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states)));

const locations = svg
  .selectAll("g")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", 10)
  .data(data)
  .join("g");
console.log(locations);
const locationGroups = locations
  .append("g")
  .attr(
    "transform",
    ({ longitude, latitude }) =>
      `translate(${projection([longitude, latitude]).join(",")})`
  );

document.body.appendChild(svg.node());
```

Output for `console.log(us.objects)` has type and geometries both fot `states` and `nation`:
[image]

Comment: It's tough to tell without seeing what your data looks like. My suggestion would be to open up your browser devtools and set a breakpoint on the line just below `"transform"` then start inspecting and stepping through to see if each variable is as you expect it to be. Is projection a function? Is longitude set there? Is latitude set there? That should give you enough info to figure out what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in scoping variable `projection`:

```
const projection = d3
  .geoAlbersUsa()
  .scale(1300)
  .translate(width / 2, height / 2);
```

I checked with `console.log(projection(-86.300568, 32.377716))` and in output was `null`. So I changed

```
`translate(${projection([longitude, latitude]).join(",")})`
```

to

```
`translate(${d3
      .geoAlbersUsa()
      .scale(1300)
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2])([longitude, latitude])
      .join(",")})`
```

And it works now!

But there is still question of how to make variable `projection` be visible in the scope?

Answer (score 1):

Your topojson API needs to have type and geometries defined. You can then use this data in your projection.

My typical set up looks like this:

```
    const mapShapes = topojson.feature(map, {
        type: 'GeometryCollection',
        geometries: data.objects.map_object.geometries
    })

    

    //projection

    const projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
    .fitExtent([[20,20],[460,500]], mapShapes)
```

Then you run the projection through the D3 geopath method:

```
//path
    const path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection)
```

Then this path can be used to draw the paths in the d attribute.

Note: map_object in a typical topojson file will be the name of the file when it was downloaded from the source.

Comment: Thx for you answer. I've updated my question with additional info about type and geometries, so can you specify bassically on my code what particualy do you think I need to change? Or what I need to check additionally?